# addToMasterFrontAction fails on component : "object is not an instance of declaring class"

Tags: jspresso

**My use case :**
I am using a view which is based on a component as model.
In this view, I want an action in order to add a new row to the list.

The component declared in model.groovy :

```groovy
Component('ComposeLoading') {
  //fields
  date_time  'etd'

  //reference
  reference 'offerPlan', ref:'OfferPlan'

  //lists
  list 'loadings', ref:'Loading'
  list 'transportOrders', ref:'TransportOrder'
}
```

The view declared in view.groovy :

```groovy
border('ComposeTrain.wizard.first.view', model:'ComposeLoading') {
  north {
    form {
      fields {
        propertyView name:'etd'
        propertyView name:'offerPlan'
      }
    }
  }
  center {
    split_horizontal {
      left {
        table(permId:'ComposeLoading.loadings.table',
               model:'ComposeLoading-loadings',
               selectionMode:'MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_CUMULATIVE_SELECTION')
      }
      right {
        split_vertical(cascadingModels:true) {
          top {
            table(permId:'ComposeLoading.transportOrders.table',
                  model:'ComposeLoading-transportOrders')
            {
              actionMap () {
                actionList('TRANSPORT_ORDER') {
                  action(ref:'addToMasterFrontAction')
                }
              }
            }
          }
          bottom {
            table(permId:'ComposeLoading.TransportOrders.loadings.table',
                   model:'TransportOrder-loadings')
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**My problem :**
when I run the application and when I click on the Add button, the addToMasterFrontAction fails with :  "object is not an instance of declaring class"

**Please find below the stacktrace :**

```groovy
ERROR <2015-04-24 08:48:44,014> org.jspresso.framework.application.frontend.controller.AbstractFrontendController : An unexpected error occurred for user demo on session 6b2afee4.
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
  at org.jspresso.framework.util.accessor.bean.BeanCollectionAccessor.addToValue(BeanCollectionAccessor.java:78)
  at org.jspresso.framework.application.backend.action.AbstractAddCollectionToMasterAction.execute(AbstractAddCollectionToMasterAction.java:116)
  at org.jspresso.framework.application.backend.AbstractBackendController.execute(AbstractBackendController.java:393)
  at org.jspresso.framework.application.frontend.controller.AbstractFrontendController.executeBackend(AbstractFrontendController.java:1534)
  at org.jspresso.framework.application.frontend.controller.AbstractFrontendController.execute(AbstractFrontendController.java:574)
  at org.jspresso.framework.application.action.AbstractAction.execute(AbstractAction.java:114)
  at org.jspresso.framework.application.frontend.action.std.AddCollectionToMasterAction.execute(AddCollectionToMasterAction.java:85)
  at org.jspresso.framework.application.frontend.controller.AbstractFrontendController.executeFrontend(AbstractFrontendController.java:1547)
  at org.jspresso.framework.application.frontend.controller.AbstractFrontendController.execute(AbstractFrontendController.java:576)
  at org.jspresso.framework.view.remote.RemoteActionFactory$ActionAdapter.actionPerformed(RemoteActionFactory.java:235)
...
```

Comment: I don't see anything obvious in the view description. I seems to be well declared and the `ComposeLoading.addToTransportOrders(...)` method should be called on your main model, i.e. the `ComposeLoading` instance. Could you post the error stacktrace ?

Comment: Please find below the stacktrace :

Comment: I added the stacktrace to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading your view name, it seems that you use it in a wizard action. The wizard action does not use a standard model as you would expect (e.g. a `ComposeLoading` component instance), but it binds a `Map`instance as root model of its views. It is completely transparent to the Jspresso binding layer since it can operate indifferently on Java beans (using accessors) or maps (using `getXXX()`  and `putXXX()`).

However, the standard collection actions that operate on model dependent collections (like `adToMasterFrontAction` or `removeFromMasterFrontAction`) are not that versatile and do not play well with maps... This is definitely a bug and I've opened an [issue](https://github.com/jspresso/jspresso-ce/issues/18) in the Jspresso GitHub for it.

Comment: It should be fixed in 4.1-SNAPSHOT

Comment: I updated my environment (mvn package -U) with your new 4.1-SNAPSHOT and all work fine.